# Interpolating the value of a build arg in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am attempting to use the docker-compose.yml from the Rails example on the Docker site. This is a Windows (WSL2/Ubuntu/Docker Desktop) machine, so any files created in the docker container are owned by root. I am trying to pass my user id and group id as args, but I can't figure out a syntax that will let me:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - USER_ID=$(id -u)
        - GROUP_ID=$(id -g)
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Comment: docker-compose files are not bash scripts. While the environment variable syntax is similar, it does not support anything more than evaluating environment variables and falling back to defaults. You would need to set env vars and pass them to docker-compose.

Comment: You should need to recompile your image just because you're running it as a different host user.  Can you have the image only write data into a known directory, and make the permissions on that directory match up?